# Child Fragment does not call onCreateOptionsMenu

Tags: android, kotlin

**onCreateOptionsMenu doesnt call, I am trying add menu in Child Fragment**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    if(activity is AppCompatActivity){
        (activity!! as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(toolbarCarpets)
    }
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"onCreateOptionsMenu")
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search,menu)
    val item : MenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
    searchView.setMenuItem(item)
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the toolbar in onCreate() method, try to add the same inside onActivityCreated()

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        if(activity is AppCompatActivity){
            (activity!! as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(toolbarCarpets)
        }
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    }
```

I guess the problem here is that 'toolbar' view object is null when you add inside the onCreate(). You can debug to check the value of *toolbarCarpets* in Oncreate(). This could be due to toolbar is added inside child fragment layout which is not inflated till OnCreateView() method.

Comment: thanx. its helped me